# Problem with server version for the right syntax to use near ' "%zoom%" order by m.nazivModela asc' at line 1

Tags: php, sql

i'm very new in php so i have a problem with this part of my code

```
$result = $db->query('select * from kupovina k join model m on k.modelID=m.modelID join boja b on k.bojaID=b.bojaID where m.nazivModela LIKE "%'.$search.'%" order by m.nazivModela asc');
```

I checked sql query in phpmyadmin database and it works corectly, but when i try to test it on my website form i have this syntax error so please help me to figure out what do i have to change?

edit: I tried to use double quotes to declare statement, and single quotes in the LIKE clause, but it's still the same error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz0no.jpg)

Comment: I believe you don't need to use GROUP BY in your case because you do 'SELECT * FROM '

Comment: Please add the literal error message, I.e. copied and pasted. Also, double check you're using standard double quotes, the message you've got in your title  looks off to me.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Sorry group by was mistake, i mean order by. I added screenshot of problem, tried to change statements and still no changes

Answer (score 1):

You use double quotes in your `LIKE` clause, you would better use single quotes instead (depending on the RDBMS you use, that could result in a syntax error). To solve this, you can change your PHP syntax : use double quotes to declare your statement, and single quotes in the `LIKE` clause.

Also, the use use of `GROUP BY ... asc` does not make sense, did you mean `ORDER BY` ?

So, maybe :

```
$result = $db->query("select * from kupovina k join model m on k.modelID=m.modelID join boja b on k.bojaID=b.bojaID where m.nazivModela LIKE '%".$search."%' order by by m.nazivModela asc");
```

Bottom line, you would be better off using a prepared statement and bind parameters - this will also protect you against any kind of sql injection.

```
my $sth =  $db->prepare("select * from kupovina k join model m on k.modelID=m.modelID join boja b on k.bojaID=b.bojaID where m.nazivModela LIKE ? order by by m.nazivModela asc");
$db->execute($sth, '%'.$search.'%');
my $result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: What says that double quotes can't be used? Do you have a link?

Comment: @JonStirling, well that's true at least for Oracle, and since the OP did not specify the RDBMS he is using...

Comment: Yeah, that definitely _could be_ the problem, or at least part of it.

Comment: You'd actaully be better off using prepared statements. Then quotes wouldn't matter.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : yep - I already mentioned that in my original answer, and I just added an example

Comment: @GMB Except OP does mention they're using phpMyAdmin, so I think we can be pretty sure which they're using.

Comment: @JonStirling : well, ok then ; mysql does support double quotes for strings - pls note that I already edited my answer after your first comment, to make that a recommendation rather than a conviction

Comment: @Andja : please upvote / accept the answer if you feel that it helped you solve the issue... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to order your results instead of grouping. Try this :

```
$result = $db->query('select * from kupovina k join model m on k.modelID=m.modelID join boja b on k.bojaID=b.bojaID where m.nazivModela LIKE "%'.$search.'%" ORDER by m.nazivModela asc');
```